# What is the difference between a JFrame and a JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

What is the difference between a `JFrame` and a `JDialog`?

Why can't we use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` for a JDialog?

Comment: What did your perusal of the JavaDocs suggest?  What did your inspection of the two components on screen reveal?

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16749798/1429432

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`JFrame` is a normal window with its normal buttons (optionally) and decorations. `JDialog` on the other side does not have a maximize and minimize buttons and usually are created with `JOptionPane` static methods, and are better fit to make them modal (they block other components until they are closed).

But both inherit from Window, so they share much functionality.

Answer (score 5):

> Why we can't use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` for `JDialog`?

Sure you can.

Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem you are having when using this value.

However you can't use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` for a `JDialog` because that value is not supported which makes sense since a `JDialog` is a "child" or "helper" window for your application which is represented by a `JFrame`. Closing a dialog should not close the application.

Comment: your right.I edit it to **setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.Exit_ON_CLOSE);**

Answer (score 1):

There are some `JDialog` constructors with a `owner` parameter which can be a `Frame`, a `Dialog` or a `Window`. A non-null value also makes the `JDialog` stay above his owner. This is complementary of the modal behavior described by Fortran.

Comment: not an answer to the question, is it? Once you'll have enough rep, you'll be able to comment :-)

Comment: The question is about the differences, so I find very interesting that a JDialog has the capabilities to stay on top of its parent without having to be modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setModal(boolean t);`
This only works on `JDialog`. User must operate on `JDialog` not other window. If they wanna operate owner windows, they must shut down this `JDialog`.

Comment: I'd use the newer [ModalityType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) constructs in lieu of the boolean modal APIs -- finer grain control and clearer intent in your code.