# Should I use JFrame or JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

In my GUI, by clicking on the button "Help", I want to open a new window within it containing som text information stored in HTML via `JEditorPane`. My question is:

1. Should I store an instance of JEditorPane object within JDialog or JFrame?
2. What kind of pros/cons both components can offer?

I do not want to make any operations within this window, it will just serve to show the text information.

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552833/1429432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences between `JDialog` and `JFrame` are, that `JDialog` has no maximize/minimize button, and you can not set a DefaultCloseOperation on it.

Also a `JDialog` blocks other components until it is closed (it waits for userinteraction). So if you use it as "Help" window, the user could not leave it open in background and continue working with your application.

If the user can only read your info text, and can not interact with your help, **you should use a** `JFrame`.

A `JDialog` should be used if the user has the choice e.g. of pressing `Ok` or `Cancel`, and he should not be able to do anything before he has choosen something.